# Smart Tomcat not interacting with local services

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

There doesn't seem to be a forum for the smart tomcat plugin, so I'll be posting here.

I'm running my tomcat from my WAR file and my Java project, and it connects to my local httpd, kafka, zookeeper, and mongo

I am using different ports for smart tomcat compared to tomcat. is this the issue? if not, what is the issue and how can it be resolved? Please let me know if you'd like me to provide more information. Thanks!

I am using Polaris Tomcat as well and it seems I am unable to find what processes are taking up my ports

I've also changed my IntelliJ version from 2023 to 2022.2.2 as it seems to work on for others on that version but I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted a different project as I was assigned a new project. I went through and set up everything the exact same way and it worked. I don't know what the error was.

Answer (score 1):

The deployment folder seems incorrect, it should be `target/{your-module-name}` for maven projects.
Or you can try `Polaris Tomcat Server` plugin, it is easier to use.
If you have further question, please let me know.

Comment: what do you mean by target?

Comment: Also polaris costs money and requires me to go on a 30 day trial

Comment: can you provide a full path so it's clear what you are talking about? whether it's an example in your directory or a path you see in my post.

Comment: Are you talking about the deployment descriptor? if so, Tomcat is pointed to D:\projects-standalone\tomcats\java-containers\conf\Catalina\localhost\containers.xml] and Smart Tomcat is pointed to: C:\Users\ktv07101\.SmartTomcat\java-containers\java-containers\conf\Catalina\localhost\containers.xml as you can see from the post. These two are different because the smart tomcat instance can be run with a debugger where as the tomcat instance cannot, so I assume there is some internal difference.

Comment: `target` is a folder that in your maven project. If you have a maven project named `hello-world`, then `target` is `hello-world/target`, it is in the same folder as `pom.xml.`

Comment: The folder tree could not show properly in comments, so I commentted in another answer. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76981512/3172039

Answer (score 0):

The structure of a regular Maven project is as follows:

```
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   ├── resources
│   └── test
└── target
    ├── tomcat-app1-1.0-SNAPSHOT
    └── tomcat-app1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
```

The  deployment folder should be `target/tomcat-app1-1.0-SNAPSHOT`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. However, I am using a gradle project, not maven. I included my file path in my question for context